# angular 2 and template: Unterminated string literal.at line 6 col 24

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template

In the code below, for some reason when I enter a new line after template it gives me an error. All my tags must be in one line `'<h1>...<h2> etc.'` - The minute I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> after the template: `'`<kbd>enter</kbd> it gives me an error.

> Unterminated string literal.at line 6 col 24 TS Error Property
>   assignment expected.at line 7 col 10 TS Error ',' expected.at line 7
>   col 25 TS Error Type expected.at line 7 col 27 TS Error Unterminated
>   regular expression literal.at line 7 col 28 TS Error ',' expected.at
>   line 8 col 1

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ponyracer-app',
    template:
    '<h1>PonyRacer</h1>
     <h2>{{numberOfUsers}}</h2>'
})
export class PonyRacerApp {

    numberOfUsers: number = 146;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `` ` `` (backticks) and not `'` (single - or double - quotes) to declare your template string:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ponyracer-app',
    template:
    `<h1>PonyRacer</h1>
     <h2>{{numberOfUsers}}</h2>`
})
export class PonyRacerApp {

    numberOfUsers: number = 146;
}
```

When you use those, you declare *template strings* and not regular strings. They are a part of ES6 (aka ECMAScript 2015):

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 / ES6 specification.

More about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html).

Comment: Thank you for actually sharing the reference as well.

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation and obvious from Angular's own documentation. The show single quotes